# From Object array to Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Object

Tags: java, object, casting

I'm getting a cast exception in the for loop while executing the `"Object[] cols = (Object[]) o;"` code. I am not suppose to change the implementation of for loop because the piece of code share is here prod Environment.

```
public class Cast {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
          List<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<Object>();

          AppGrpCBSModel appGrpCBSModel = new AppGrpCBSModel();
          RCBSAppGroupModel rcbsAppGroupModel = new RCBSAppGroupModel();
          rcbsAppGroupModel.setSortCode("012345");
          appGrpCBSModel.setHeritage(HeritageNm.HBOS.value());
          resultList.add(rcbsAppGroupModel);
          resultList.add(appGrpCBSModel);


          if (!resultList.isEmpty() && resultList != null) {

                 for (Object o : resultList) {
                       Object[] cols = (Object[]) o;
                       appGrpCBSModel = (AppGrpCBSModel) cols[0];
                       rcbsAppGroupModel = (RCBSAppGroupModel) cols[1];

   }
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think an `Object` is an `Object[]`?

Comment: Also, given the code you have right now, wouldn't be more useful to just iterate with 'for (Object[] o : resultList)' instead?

Comment: The list contains an instance of RCBSAppGroupModel and an instance of AppGrpCBSModel. So clearly not any array. Why do you think you can cast an RCBSAppGroupModel to an array?

Comment: Your variables are already set. I don't know what your code does but it seems like you are trying to set the same values to existing variables. You don't actually need the for loop. Just delete it.

Comment: No @vc73 - because `resultList` is _not_ a `List<Object[]>`, so you're just moving the error up one line. resultList does not, in fact, contain Object-arrays, so you can't cast an element from the list to an `(Object[])` no matter where you put the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `List<Object>` you are iterating through, but you are trying to cast each member of the list as an `Object[]` instead of `Object`. You either need to change your list to a `List<Object[]>` or cast to `Object` instead of `Object[]`

Comment: I have tried as below also but same error is poping out                                         List<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> resultList1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
 AppGrpCBSModel appGrpCBSModel = new AppGrpCBSModel();
              RCBSAppGroupModel rcbsAppGroupModel = new RCBSAppGroupModel();
 rcbsAppGroupModel.setSortCode("012345");
appGrpCBSModel.setHeritage(HeritageNm.HBOS.value());
resultList1.add(rcbsAppGroupModel);
resultList1.add(appGrpCBSModel);
              resultList.add(resultList1);

Comment: @user2964628 where is the stack trace coming from?